# How to default the Project Description with the "CustomerID"

Tags: acumatica

I am attempting to insert the Customer ID at the beginning of the Project Description.  I believe the two opportunities to do this are 1) upon selection of a customer and 2) upon selection of template if the customer has already been selected.  I also believe that I want to extend the PM.ProjectEntry business logic.  I am having two issues:

1. Using the same code from the source code in the extension is giving me an error when I try to select the customer record on the CustomerID field updated event.  The error is identified in the code below.
2. I have an TemplateID field updated event and what I thought was an extension of the DefaultFromTemplateProjectSettings event.  No errors but the description field does not get modified.

```
namespace PX.Objects.PM
{
  public class ProjectEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.PM.ProjectEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
  
    // Attempt to modify the project description line after a customer has been selected
    protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<PMProject, PMProject.customerID> e, PXFieldUpdated baseMethod)
    {
      baseMethod(e.Cache, e.Args);

      if (e.Row != null)
      {
        // Line 3 of this select statement errors with:
        // Argument 1: cannot convert from 'PX.Objects.PM.ProjectEntry_Extension' to 'PX.Data.PXGraph'
        Customer customer = new PXSelect<Customer,
          Where<Customer.bAccountID,
          Equal<Required<Customer.bAccountID>>>>(this).Select(e.Row.CustomerID);
        
        if (customer != null)
        {
          e.Cache.SetValueExt<PMProject.description>(e.Row, customer.AcctCD + " " + e.Row.Description);
        }
      }
    }

    // Two attempts to modify the project descrition after the project template has been selected
    // Neither of these two codes error, they just don't update the project description field
    // "customer.AcctCD" would be determined similar to the above process that currently errors
    protected virtual void DefaultFromTemplateProjectSettings(PMProject prj, PMProject templ)
    {
      prj.Description = "customer.AcctCD" + ": " + templ.Description;
    }
      
    protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<PMProject, PMProject.templateID> e, PXFieldUpdated baseMethod)
    {
      baseMethod(e.Cache, e.Args);

      if (e.Row != null)
      {
        e.Cache.SetValueExt<PMProject.description>(e.Row, "customer.AcctCD" + ": " + e.Row.Description);
      }
    }
      
    #endregion
  }
}
```

In the PM.ProjectEntry business logic, I found the following:

```
protected virtual void OnDefaultFromTemplateTasksInserted(ProjectEntry target, Dictionary<int, int> taskMap)
{
    //this method is used to extend DefaultFromTemplate in Customizations.
}
```

So, I tried the following in my customization.  There are no errors but it doesn't alter the project description when the template is selected.

```
protected virtual void OnDefaultFromTemplateTasksInserted(PMProject prj, PMProject templ, Dictionary<int, int> taskMap)
{
  prj.Description = "CustomerID: " + templ.Description;
}
```

Without the "CustomerID: ", that is the line of code used in the DefaultFromTemplateProjectSettings object.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first error, you simply need to change the line

```
Customer customer = new PXSelect<Customer,
      Where<Customer.bAccountID,
      Equal<Required<Customer.bAccountID>>>>(this).Select(e.Row.CustomerID);
```

to

```
Customer customer = new PXSelect<Customer,
      Where<Customer.bAccountID,
      Equal<Required<Customer.bAccountID>>>>(this.Base).Select(e.Row.CustomerID);
```

You need to pass the `PXGraph` instance to the `PXSelect` constructor and you currently are passing `this` which is `PXGraphExtension`.

Regarding the second part, I don't think anonymous event handlers have the concept of the BaseMethod, so I would try to remove the second parameter of that function.

Comment: Your answer to the first error fixed the issue.

Comment: On the second error, I found this snippet of code in the PM.ProjectEntry business logic:

        protected virtual void OnCopyPasteTasksInserted(ProjectEntry target, Dictionary<int, int> taskMap)
 {
            //this method is used to extend Copy in Customizations.
 }

So, I tried this in my customization.  No error, just doesn't work.

        protected virtual void OnDefaultFromTemplateTasksInserted(PMProject prj, PMProject templ, Dictionary<int, int> taskMap)
        {
          prj.Description = "CustomerID: " + templ.Description;
        }

Answer (score 0):

With a little help I have a solution.

```
namespace PX.Objects.PM
{
  public class ProjectEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.PM.ProjectEntry>
{
#region Event Handlers

// Attempt to modify the project description line after a customer has been selected
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<PMProject, PMProject.customerID> e, PXFieldUpdated baseMethod)
{
  baseMethod(e.Cache, e.Args);

  if (e.Row != null)   // attempted to prevent repatition --  && e.Row.Description.IndexOf(":") > 0
  {
    Customer customer = new PXSelect<Customer,
      Where<Customer.bAccountID,
      Equal<Required<Customer.bAccountID>>>>(this.Base).Select(e.Row.CustomerID);
    
    if (customer != null)
    {
      e.Cache.SetValueExt<PMProject.description>(e.Row, customer.AcctCD + ": " + e.Row.Description);
    }
  }
}

// Attempt to modify the project description line after a template has been selected
public delegate void DefaultFromTemplateDelegate(PMProject prj, int? templateID, ProjectEntry.DefaultFromTemplateSettings settings);
[PXOverride]
public void DefaultFromTemplate(PMProject prj, int? templateID, ProjectEntry.DefaultFromTemplateSettings settings, DefaultFromTemplateDelegate baseMethod)
{
  baseMethod(prj, templateID, settings);
  if (Base.Project.Current.CustomerID != null)
  {
    Customer customer = new PXSelect<Customer,
      Where<Customer.bAccountID,
      Equal<Required<Customer.bAccountID>>>>(this.Base).Select(prj.CustomerID);
    if (customer != null)
    {
      Base.Project.Current.Description = customer?.AcctCD + ": " + Base.Project.Current.Description;
    }
  }
}
  
#endregion
}
}
```